# Plugin translation not working apart from name and description

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, localization

I wrote a plugin that creates a custom post type and I tried to translate it using Poedit, but it's not *fully* working. I did translate a few other plugins before and I'm not sure what's causing this error:

The plugin's name and description are correctly translated in the backend, but no post type names are translated.

## Full Example

**`File Structure`**

```
test
├── languages
│   ├── test-de_DE.mo
│   ├── test-de_DE.po
│   └── test.pot
└── test.php
```

I defined the Text Domain `test` and Domain Path `\languages` in the plugin header in `test.php`.

The post type is defined in the same file like so:

**`test.php`**

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: A Test
 * Description: A Test Plugin
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Text Domain: test
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */

function test_custom_post_types()
{
    register_post_type('test_post', [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('Test Posts', 'test'),
            'menu_name' => __('Test Posts', 'test'),
        ],
        'public' => true,
    ]);
}
add_action('init', 'test_custom_post_types');
```

I created a `.pot` file using the `wp-cli` command `i18n make-pot .\wp-content\plugins\test\`

**`languages/test.pot`**

```
# Copyright (C) 2020 
# This file is distributed under the same license as the A Test plugin.
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: A Test 1.0.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/test\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-06-12T15:08:36+02:00\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"X-Generator: WP-CLI 2.4.0\n"
"X-Domain: test\n"

#. Plugin Name of the plugin
msgid "A Test"
msgstr ""

#. Description of the plugin
msgid "A Test Plugin"
msgstr ""

#: test.php:15
#: test.php:16
msgid "Test Posts"
msgstr ""
```

Then I used Poedit to create the german `.po` and `.mo` files.

With the plugin activated I can see the plugin's name and description in german, but the added post type still shows up in english.

This is the .po file generated by Poedit:

**`languages/test-de_DE.po`**

```
# Copyright (C) 2020 
# This file is distributed under the same license as the A Test plugin.
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: A Test 1.0.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/test\n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-06-12T15:08:36+02:00\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2020-06-12 15:09+0200\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.3.1\n"
"X-Domain: test\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: de_DE\n"

#. Plugin Name of the plugin
msgid "A Test"
msgstr "Ein Test"

#. Description of the plugin
msgid "A Test Plugin"
msgstr "Ein Test-Plugin"

#: test.php:15 test.php:16
msgid "Test Posts"
msgstr "Test Beiträge"
```

---

As a bonus, it also doesn't translate (server side rendered) Gutenberg blocks that I created in the same plugin.

Any ideas how to fix the missing translations? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Seems like you forgot to load the text domain

[The plugin handbook says that:](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#loading-text-domain)

> You need to load the MO file with your plugin’s translations. You can
>   load them by calling the function
>   [`load_plugin_textdomain()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/)
>   (and
>   [`load_muplugin_textdomain()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_muplugin_textdomain/)
>   if your plugin will be used as a Must-Use plugin). This call loads
>   `{text-domain}-{locale}.mo` from your plugin’s base directory.

So based on the example there, you could add this to your main plugin file (`test.php`):

```php
function test_load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'test', false, basename( __DIR__ ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'test_load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

Comment: Oh yes, that's correct! I totally skipped that part and always left it out! I wonder how I never noticed missing translations in other plugins D: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I also encountered this issue, the translations simply were not used.
The hook function was fine, the `load_plugin_textdomain` invocation was also fine and returned `true` for success, the individual MO-files were correctly named `translationdomain-locale1_locale2.mo`.

The reason was actually the `Language` field inside the MO-files (and in the PO-files as those were compiled from it): It was set to `de` (German) instead to `de_DE` (German (Germany)). E.g. in the popular PO-Editor Poedit, the language in the translation properties of the catalog must be set to `German (Germany)` instead to just `German`.
WordPress will not fall back to plain `de` (even with the language fallback plugin, it can only fall back from `de_DE_formal` to `de_DE`).
After changing the language from `de` to `de_DE` in the PO-file and re-compiled the MO-files, WordPress correctly used the translated strings from those MO-files.
For formal German this issue does not arise with Poedit, as there is only `German (Germany) ("Sie")` available.